VS Code Extension Not Showing "HELLO WORLD" Command
I am developing a custom "Hello World" extension for Visual Studio Code using the official extension generator and the Yeoman template. While I followed all the steps in the official documentation, my custom command does not appear in the Command Palette in the Extension Development Host window.
What I Did:
I created a new extension using the following command: npm install --global yo generator-code
yo code
I selected a TypeScript-based extension and configured it as follows:
Extension Name: helloworld
Command ID: helloworld.helloWorld
Default options for other prompts.
I installed the required dependencies by running npm install
The dependencies were installed successfully, though I saw some warnings about deprecated packages: Running npm install for you to install the required dependencies.
npm warn deprecated inflight@1.0.6: This module is not supported, and leaks memory. Do not use it. Check out lru-cache if you want a good and tested way to coalesce async requests by a key value, which is much more comprehensive and powerful.

npm warn deprecated glob@7.2.3: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported

npm warn deprecated glob@8.1.0: Glob versions prior to v9 are no longer supported

the exstension.ts:
// The module 'vscode' contains the VS Code extensibility API
// Import the module and reference it with the alias vscode in your code below
import * as vscode from 'vscode';

// This method is called when your extension is activated
// Your extension is activated the very first time the command is executed
export function activate(context: vscode.ExtensionContext) {

    // Use the console to output diagnostic information (console.log) and errors (console.error)
    // This line of code will only be executed once when your extension is activated
    console.log('Congratulations, your extension "helloworld" is now active!');

    // The command has been defined in the package.json file
    // Now provide the implementation of the command with registerCommand
    // The commandId parameter must match the command field in package.json
    const disposable = vscode.commands.registerCommand('helloworld.helloWorld', () => {
        // The code you place here will be executed every time your command is executed
        // Display a message box to the user
        vscode.window.showInformationMessage('Hello World from  HelloWorld!');
    });

    context.subscriptions.push(disposable);
}

// This method is called when your extension is deactivated
export function deactivate() {}

the package.json file:
{
  "name": "helloworld",
  "displayName": " HelloWorld",
  "description": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "engines": {
    "vscode": "^1.95.0"
  },
  "categories": [
    "Other"
  ],
  "activationEvents": [],
  "main": "./out/extension.js",
  "contributes": {
    "commands": [
      {
        "command": "helloworld.helloWorld",
        "title": "Hello World"
      }
    ]
  },
  "scripts": {
    "vscode:prepublish": "npm run compile",
    "compile": "tsc -p ./",
    "watch": "tsc -watch -p ./",
    "pretest": "npm run compile && npm run lint",
    "lint": "eslint src",
    "test": "vscode-test"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mocha": "^10.0.9",
    "@types/node": "20.x",
    "@types/vscode": "^1.95.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^8.10.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^8.7.0",
    "@vscode/test-cli": "^0.0.10",
    "@vscode/test-electron": "^2.4.1",
    "eslint": "^9.13.0",
    "typescript": "^5.7.2"
  }
}

Expected Behavior:
The command Hello World should appear in the Command Palette when I type "Hello World" in the new Extension Development Host.
Actual Behavior:
The command Hello World does not appear in the Command Palette.
I do not see any errors in the Extension Host logs and also I dont see any other hello world extenstions.
What I Tried:
Verified that activationEvents and commands in package.json match the command registered in src/extension.ts.
Recompiled the extension with npm run compile.
Ran Developer: Reload Window in the Extension Development Host.
Checked for conflicts with other extensions that may also register a "Hello World" command.
Environment:
Visual Studio Code Version: 1.95.3  (match the version in the package.json file)
Why is my custom "Hello World" command not appearing in the Command Palette? Are there additional debugging steps or configurations I might have missed?
Current results when I search
